# Print out the directory size with condition

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I want to check the directory size:

• Low if the directory uses less than 3 MB of disk space

• Medium if the directory uses more than 3 MB and less than 8 MB of disk space

• High if the directory uses equal to or more than 8 MB disk space

For example:

```
> ./size.sh /usr/bin
High
> ./size.sh /tmp
Low
```

Here is the code that I try even though the folder contains this directory I still cannot do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="breakfast"
DIRSIZE=`du -h "$dir"`
a=3145728
b=8388608
if (DIRSIZE -le "$a"); then 
    echo "Low"
else if (DIRSIZE -gt "$a" && DIRSIZE -lt "$b")
    echo "Medium"
else if (DIRSIZE -ge "$b")
    echo "High"
fi
```

Output:

```
sh quota.sh
: not found:
du: cannot access 'breakfast'$'\r': No such file or directory
quota.sh: 9: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Comment: The `\r`s mean your file is in DOS/Windows format.

Comment: Beyond that, `-gt` is an argument to the `test` command, also called `[`. It doesn't make sense in another context -- `(` does not run `test`.

Comment: You also can't just use `DIRSIZE` and expect the variable name to be replaced with a value except in an arithmetic context, and if you _were_ in an arithmetic context then `-gt` wouldn't be legal syntax, you'd need to use `>` instead.

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your scripts through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: You are missing the `then` after `else if`

Comment: Another thing, though -- think about what dataformats things write. When you add the `-h` argument to `du`, for example, that makes it write things out in human units. Something written as a string in human units is not a number, so you can't _compare it to_ a number.

Comment: @mashuptwice, ...and _also_ the first `then` isn't recognized because it parses as `$'then\r'` on account of the trailing carriage return (because the script is saved as a DOS text file instead of a UNIX one).